# Find 1st child in ul->li list

Tags: php

I'm using [php simple dom](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/)

I have a UL of class .myclass and a bunch of LI's but some of them have UL's inside the LI's. I want to grab the first a href in both the LI and the LI->UL
My code so far:

```
foreach ( $html->find('ul.myclass') as $e) { 
      echo $e->first_child()->find('li, a',0)->href . '<br/>';   
}
```

This gets me the LI->A but not the li->ul->A's. I'm not 100% certain that php simple dom is up to the job, any ideas what I should do? Would it be doable in PHP DomDocument or jquery?

Comment: I would think it would be easier to `foreach` over this selector instead: `ul.myclass li`

Comment: In jQuery (or any CSS like selectors) `find('li:first a:first')`  or direct descendant `find('>li>a')`  Which return only the `li` that are children of that `ul` not ones like `ul li ul li` that are nested, so the last `li` there is grandchild and would not be returned by direct descendant `>`.  Or you can combine them `find('>li:first>a:first')` etc. as you like.  For server side, PHPQuery is something I have used for DOM parsing it lets you use jQuery like selectors and syntax in PHP including the above, if I remember right. For example you can even do `->eq(1)` or in jQuery `.eq(1)`

Comment: [PHPQuery](https://packagist.org/packages/phpquery/phpquery) in Composer Packagist

Comment: wouldn't it be $e->first_child()->find('a',0)->href - since the first child is the li so you just want to look for the a in that container

Comment: Thank you guys, making the foreach  ul.myclass li results in Notice: Trying to get property 'href' of non-object in /var/www/example.com/test6.php on line 25. PHPQuery looks interesting. $e->first_child()->find('a',0)->href  gives the same result as $e->first_child()->find('li, a',0)->href What about using php to loop through the html returned by $html->find('ul.myclass') as $e ? So many choices eek!!!!

Comment: If you change the foreach selector, that means you have to change the inner code as well, because now you are looking at each `li` not each `ul`.  If you only have one `ul.myclass`, it is pointless to create a foreach loop over that one item.  You want a foreach loop over all the list items inside that `ul`.